# Marvel Quiz in Python

Tags: python

I am coding a Marvel Quiz in Python and one of the questions is 'What are the names of all the names of the guardians from guardians of the galaxy' Since there is more than 1 answer how do i make it that when i have:
if answer == "Star Lord, Drax, Gamora, Nebula, Rocket, Groot"

the one taking the quiz does not have to put it in in the same order as typed in the question?

Thanks in advance!!

My code atm:

```py
answer = input("9. What are the names of all the guardians from Guardians of the Galaxy? ")
if answer =="Star Lord, Gamora, Rocket, Drax, Groot, Mantis, Nebula":
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

Comment: Put all the names in a set.  For each name in the answer, check if the answer is in the set.  You know, the canonical spelling is "Star-Lord" with a hyphen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the KIND of thing you need.  This doesn't handle "Star Lord" vs "Star-Lord" vs "StarLord".

```
answers = set(["Star Lord", "Gamora", "Rocket", "Drax", "Groot", "Mantis", "Nebula"])
answer = input("9. What are the names of all the guardians from Guardians of the Galaxy? ") 
yes = no = 0
for word in answer.split(','):
    if word.strip() in answers:
        yes += 1
    else:
        no += 1

if yes == len(answers):
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print(f"You got {yes} names,but there are {len(answers)} Guardians.")
```

### Followup

More clever one-liner:

```
answers = set(["Star Lord", "Gamora", "Rocket", "Drax", "Groot", "Mantis", "Nebula"])
answer = input("9. What are the names of all the guardians from Guardians of the Galaxy? ") 
yes = sum( word.strip() in answers for word in answer.split(','))
if yes == len(answers):
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print(f"You got {yes} names,but there are {len(answers)} Guardians.")
```

Comment: You probably should make sure `no` is 0 since having all of them plus "Iron Man" doesn't make sense to count as a correct answer, or at least mention that in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can check the answer:

```
def get_answer_9(answer):
    # converts the answer into something easier to work with
    answer = answer.split(', ')
    
    # checks answer
    for a in answer:
        if a in ['Star Lord', 'Gamora', 'Rocket', 'Drax', 'Groot', 'Mantis', 'Nebula']:
            continue
        return False
    return True

answer = input('9. What are the names of all the guardians from Guardians of the Galaxy?(Hint: There are 7) ') 
a = get_answer_9(answer)
if a: 
    print('Correct!') 
else: 
    print('Incorrect!')
```

I hope it helps!